# Avoid reaching the rate limit

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the issue with understanding actually how many tweets I can get without being stuck with "Rate limit reached. Sleeping for...". What I want to do is building a crawler which will be able to get as much tweets as possible (per 15-minute session) without being blocked.

```py
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, compression=True)
z = 0
while z <= 160:
    print(z)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = "place:{}".format(place_id), count = 10, tweet_mode = "extended", lang = "pl").items():

        if len(str(tweet.place.name)) != 0:
            tweet_date.append(tweet.created_at)
            tweet_content.append(tweet.full_text)
            tweet_location.append(tweet.place.name)
            tweet_author.append(tweet.author)

    time.sleep(5)
    z += 1
```

As I was reading about limits before what I understood is that with every request one can get 100 tweets (in my case count is 10, just to avoid getting the same tweets all the time). And there are 180 request which can be made in 15 minutes. So I thought that this code will easily get 10 tweets after every request without exceeding the limit. Instead after one iterration I got "Rate limit reached. Sleeping for...". What is the issue here? It is clear for me that I do not properly understand API's request limit but have no idea how to overcome this, making my crawler work smoothly without being forced to sleep.

Thanks for every advice. Best wishes